# DataTables- aoData is null when expanding details of a row

Tags: datatables

I'm using a drilldown DataTable found [here](http://www.datatables.net/blog/Drill-down_rows).

The datatable exists inside an accordion.  The user would select the category by clicking it, it expands out to display a datatable relevant to that category.  The function initTable is called when the user clicks the category.

DataTables doc says to use this code to account for multiple dataTables on a page, but I can't get that to work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dataTable').dataTable();
} );
```

What I did is rather than use "#example", I replaced it with "#" + category, which 99% works.  I can click a category, drill down to see additional data on a row, switch to a new category, do the same thing.

What doesn't work is this - if I click a category, then either close that category or go to another and then go back to the first - expanding a row then throws an error "aoData" is null or not an object.  The following 3 images show what I'm talking about.  Notice in 3rd image detail row doesn't display.

I can't insert images, but I've posted them [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIrRF.png) to show what I'm talking about.

Here's the initTable function that's called to create the table.  I'm using bDestroy to destroy the existing table before creating the new one.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
function initTable(category, facility)
{
  if (gsCategory == "")
    gsCategory = category;
  else if (gsCategory == category)
    gbToggle = !gbToggle;
  else
    gbToggle = false;

  gsCategory = category;

  if (gbToggle == false)
  {
    gsCategory = category;

    var select = document.forms[0].selFacility;
    var facility = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

    document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';

    var patJson = getJson(facility, category);
    var anOpen = [];
    var sImageUrl = "../images/";
    makeTable(category);

    document.body.style.cursor = 'default';

    var oTable = $('#'+category).dataTable( {
      "bProcessing": false,
      "bDestroy": true,
      "aaData": patJson,
      "bAutoWidth": false,
      "aoColumns": [
        {
         "mDataProp": null, 
         "sClass": "control center", 
         "sDefaultContent": '<img src="'+sImageUrl+'details_open.png'+'">',
         "sWidth": "5%"
        },
        { "mDataProp": "S_PAT_NAME", "sWidth": "30%" },
        { "mDataProp": "S_AGE", "sWidth": "15%"},
        { "mDataProp": "S_FIN", "sWidth": "30%"},
        { "mDataProp": "S_ROOM_BED", "sWidth": "20%" }
      ]
    } );

    $('#'+category+' td.control').live( 'click', function () 
    {
      var nTr = this.parentNode;
      var i = $.inArray( nTr, anOpen );

      if ( i === -1 ) 
      {
        $('img', this).attr( 'src', sImageUrl+"details_close.png" );
        var nDetailsRow = oTable.fnOpen( nTr, fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr), 'details' );
        $('div.innerDetails', nDetailsRow).slideDown();
        anOpen.push( nTr );
      }
      else 
      {
        $('img', this).attr( 'src', sImageUrl+"details_open.png" );
        $('div.innerDetails', $(nTr).next()[0]).slideUp( function () 
        {
          oTable.fnClose( nTr );
          anOpen.splice( i, 1 );
        } );
      }
    } );
  }
}
function fnFormatDetails( oTable, nTr )
{
  var oData = oTable.fnGetData( nTr );
  var sOut = 
     '<div class="innerDetails">'+
        '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
           '<tr><td>Trigger Order:</td><td>'+oData.S_TRIGGER_MED+'</td></tr>'+
           '<tr><td>Allergies:</td><td>'+oData.S_ALLERGIES+'</td></tr>'
        '</table>'+
     '</div>';
  return sOut;
}
```